# Lock camera position to the User's location google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, camera, google-maps-android-api-2

Lock camera position to the User's location using Button OnClick.

Currently my button camera position is like this:

```
    public void navigate(View view) {
    float mapZoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom >=16 ? mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom : 16;
    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLng)
                    .bearing(20)
                    .tilt(90)
                    .zoom(mapZoom)
                    .build();

    mMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}
```

I want to follow user's location while he/she is moving that the camera position is locked.

What i'm trying to implement is like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn7aS.jpg

Where i achieve the camera angle, but i haven't yet implement the following:
- Follow user's location with the camera locked.
- Adjust Camera position when the user turned left or right.

Comment: can u be more specific pls..

Comment: Updated the post.